# Changing termux repository

Tags: termux

I am trying to change repository of termux to fix update error by using cmd termux-change-repo
But it's not working is there anyone  who can tell the solution ?
Note: app on fdroid is not compatible with my phone

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

```
pkg remove game-repo -y
pkg remove science-repo -y
pkg update
```

have fun.